# Is there any way i can remove the line which is shown in MASKEDTEXTBOX fields when we set the mask?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

The line that appears when we set the mask of a masked text box in winforms for c# does not seem attractive at all to me .I want to know if there is any way i can set the mask of 
the masked text box and that line is not shown???

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In VB.NET, the MaskedTextBox has a property called PromptChar (I'm sure it's the same in C#). It defaults to the underscore that you see. Change that.

Comment: But that value can't be null and i don't want any prompchar in it so if there is any way

Answer (score 2):

I was able to go to the designer code and set the char as an empty space.

```
this.mtxtPanel.Mask = "0000";
this.mtxtPanel.PromptChar = ' ';
```